# How to convert from Date to Int

Tags: java, int, simpledateformat

I'm Trying to get the current day value (example. 12) then assign it to a variable (example. today= 12).

```
    DateFormat DateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat ("dd");

    //get current day time with Date()
    Date day= new Date ();

    int day1 = Integer.valueOf(day);
```

Or

```
    DateFormat DateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat ("dd");

    //get current day time with Date()
    Date day= new Date ();

    int day1 = day;
```

But it didn't work :(

There's another way?

Sorry for not clearing the meaning enough in my preview question :)

Comment: What do you think you are doing? Have you looked at the javadoc of `Date`?

Comment: Your question title should be *How to get the day from a Date variable as int?*

Answer (score 2):

Apart from @R.J answer, you can use a `Calendar` and get the day:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date());
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
int day1 = Integer.valueOf(DateFormat.format(day));
```

But I must say the naming convention is very bad.